# How to test registration on django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I'm new to django rest framework.
I'm following this [tutorial](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) to make a registration/login and using facebook authentication.
I finish the tutorial everything looks fine.
But I would like to try to register a user and try it also with facebook. But I don't know how to try. I know it's a noob question.
I've made a user using the django createsuperuser command.
I can login using the `http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/login/` url and it return me a key. But I'm logged in and can access the admin for example.
There is `http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/registration/` url for registration but there is no form.
There is also `http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/facebook/` but it ask me an access token.

So I know it's sound very basic but I didn't find how to register

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use  CURL to interact with the API.
Something like this

$ curl -X POST -d 'username=admin&password=1234' 
http://localhost:8000/register/

OR go through this [link](http://www.madewithtea.com/simple-todo-api-with-django-and-oauth2.html)
it might help you.